# How can I get zero space between images when I horizontally align them?

Tags: html, css, image

[image]

How can I adjust the code so that there is no space between each image and also how to keep them from overlapping. I tried to add another image but one ended up overlapping it. I have tried looking it up but no matter what I try it just doesn't work.

```css
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.row::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.text {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!--IMAGES-->
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a0/4f/0a/a04f0abbac3ebf36f1f302937a45071f.jpg" height="300px" width="300px" alt="" />
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/5f/09/7c/5f097ceb782476bae9dc15ec1dd364b1.jpg" height="300px" width="300px" alt="" />
  </div>

  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/68/c7/9f/68c79f2f9203f086d70e75985bf258f2--funny-pets-funny-animals.jpg" height="300px" width="300px" alt="" />
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: do you want the images to be responsives?

Answer (score 0):

You could use flexbox

```
    <div class="row_flex">
    <div class="column_flex">
        <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a0/4f/0a/a04f0abbac3ebf36f1f302937a45071f.jpg" 
        height="300px" width="300px" alt="" />
    </div>
    
    <div class="column_flex">
        <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/5f/09/7c/5f097ceb782476bae9dc15ec1dd364b1.jpg" 
        height="300px" width="300px" alt="" />
    </div>
    
    <div class="column_flex">
        <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/68/c7/9f/68c79f2f9203f086d70e75985bf258f2--funny-pets-funny-animals.jpg" 
        height="300px" width="300px" alt="" />
        
        
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
    .row_flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

I have changed your class names by adding the word "flex" as it looks like you're using something like Zurb foundation or bootstrap, where you wouldn't want to change the properties of "row" and "column" as the rest of your site will likely depend on them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want images to be a little repsonsive I would suggest the following:

```css
.column {
  padding: 5px;
  /* flex: 1;
  flex-basis: 33%; */
  max-width: calc(33vw - 10px);
  display: flex;
}
.column img {
  max-width: inherit;
}

/* .row::after {
            content:"";
           // display: table;
            clear: both;
            } */

.text {
  text-align: center;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
            <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a0/4f/0a/a04f0abbac3ebf36f1f302937a45071f.jpg" 
            alt="" />
        </div>
        
        <div class="column">
            <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/5f/09/7c/5f097ceb782476bae9dc15ec1dd364b1.jpg" 
           alt="" />
        </div>
        
        <div class="column">
            <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/68/c7/9f/68c79f2f9203f086d70e75985bf258f2--funny-pets-funny-animals.jpg" 
             alt="" />
            
            
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether or not you want this to run for other people you could make your own image on paint where you combine all 3 of the other images and then create an indirect path by guiding it to your images file. There are better methods if you want to be able to give the code to other people or have it work for other people on a browser involving more difficult code but if this is just going to be displayed on your computer and will not go to the public, I think that this would be much easier than coding the solution. That is, unless you are using bootstrap or another adapter.